# Leverage Browser Caching for WOFF fonts

Tags: seo

Google Page Speed inisght still tells me to leverage Browser Caching for some .woff fonts:

/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.1 
/rssocial-font.woff?13037212

in my .htaccesss file I have:

```
 # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 1.0
ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"
```

but it looks like they are ignored...

Comment: Is the font being served from your site? Can you include the HTTP response headers?

Comment: you can have a look at the site directly: www.sagreinitalia.it

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax looks correct but it's actually being served as "access plus 2 days".

This suggests either your .htaccess is being completely ignored or its being overridden (either later in .htaccess or by other config).

I would say though that when loading 200 resources (70 of which from an advertising domain), that "only" caching 2 fonts (out of those 200 resources) for two days isn't really that big a deal or that big a performance drag.

Reduce your number of resources and domains for a much bigger impact.